# How to recognizing the header row when filtering in Excel?

Tags: excel

When I use this API : Range.AutoFilter, it can filter the whole sheet. Even when I don't specify a header ,Excel is able to guess my header row. My question is :How can I implement it?I can't figure out the rules about guessing a header row.

Comment: Do you mean how can you specify the autofilter range? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: If I didn't set a header in my autofilter range,when filtering the data range,Excel will guess which row may be the header row.I'd like to know how does Excel achieve it.

Comment: If you had to guess by looking at a worksheet which was the header row, how would *you* do it?  Excel probably uses a similar method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself yesterday.Here are the main rules:

1. If you don't specify a range to filter,Excel will find out which row
   is the first row having a cell with value.We can mark it as row1.
2. Recognize whether there is an empty cell in the entire row. (Excel
       will clip a data Range called UsedRange,which means the range
       existing a real value.The column started from the UsedRange's first
       row,and the last column is the last column of UsedRange , you can
       check the usedRange with API:sheet.UsedRange.select).
3. If there is a blank cell in row1, comparing row2 and row3, find out
   whether they
       have the same cell format.If not, the header row is row2,otherwise,
       the header row is row1.
4. If there isn't any blank cell in row1,
       comparing the cell format between row1 and row2. here is the
       Pseudocode：

Typing English is too difficult,writing code is easier....

```
if (Row1's cell format == Row2's cell format)
{ 
       if (row2's cell format == row3's cell format)
              header_row = row1;
       else 
              header_row = row2;
}
else 
{
       header_row = row1;
}
```